# Why isn't $\langle i,1\rangle=0$ for a complex inner product?

Tags: complex-numbers, inner-products

This is probably trivial, but it's really bugging me. 
According to the inner product on $\mathbb{C}$ (i.e. $\langle z,w\rangle=z\overline{w}$), $\langle i, 1\rangle\neq 0$. I'd like to say that $i$ and $1$ are orthogonal (specifically in the context of defining what it means for a vector in $\mathbb{C}$ to be tangent to the unit circle), but the inner product disagrees.

Comment: They are orthogonal when you view $\mathbb{C}$ as a real vector space, with inner product $\operatorname{Re} z\overline{w}$. When you view it as a complex vector space, they are linearly dependent, so not orthogonal.

Comment: The inner product you are using is used for complex vector spaces. What Daniel is saying is that $\mathbb C$, as a complex vector space, is only one dimensional and interpreted that way there can be no orthogonality. The answer by Menhi is interpreting $\mathbb C$ as a two dimensional real vector space. You have to be clear which one it is that you need in your case.

Comment: Ok, what about in $\mathbb{C}^n$? If $x$ is in the unit sphere in $\mathbb{C}^n$, I'd like to say that $ix$ is orthogonal to $x$, but the inner product is $i$ again.

Comment: If you want $ix$ orthogonal to $x$, you must view it as a real vector space.

Comment: If $\lambda\in\Bbb C$, then $\lambda x$ is parallel to $x$ for all $x\in\Bbb C^n$. Compare this to the real case.

Answer (score 2):

You have to write them in the vector form as

> $$ 1 \equiv   (1,0), \quad  i \equiv (0,1).$$