# $x-y$ is not orthogonal to $x+y$ when $\|x\|=\|y\|$ in complex vector space?

Tags: linear-algebra

$x-y$ is not orthogonal to $x+y$ when $\|x\|=\|y\|$ in complex vector space $\Bbb C^n$? Just assume standard inner product $\langle x,y\rangle=x^Hy$ where $H$ denotes conjugate transpose, and $\|x\|=x^Hx$ then

$(x+y)^H(x-y)=y^Hx-x^Hy$

I don't think above is necessarily zero since $x^Hy=\overline {{y^H}x} $. This is weird because in $\Bbb R^n$, $x+y$ is always orthogonal to $x-y$ when $\|x\|=\|y\|$, due to $x^Ty=y^Tx$. What would be the analogous claim for this in complex vector space?

Comment: See [Orthogonality in Complex Plane](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/573792/orthogonality-in-complex-plane). The inner product in $\mathbb{C}$, considered as a *real* (not complex) vector space, is $\langle z, w \rangle = \operatorname{Re}{(z \bar w)}\,$.

Comment: The conventional notation for the conjugate transpose of a matrix $M$ is $M^*$. This naturally applies to row/column vectors.

Comment: @TheoBendit Notations are not universal.  $M^H$ is also sometimes used.

Comment: @RobertIsrael I've never seen it. Good to know.